# How to change the backgroundColor of a UIButton on on UIControlStateSelected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, storyboard

I have a `UIButton` that currently sets the background color to clear and sets a background image like so:

```
[[currentDay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor];
[currentDay setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

I want when the button is not selected for the background colour to be set back to the original it was set as on the storyboard.

You would have thought there would be a `forState` for the `setBackgroundColor` attribute but there does not appear to be.

example:

```
[[currentDay setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

would be ideal if it existed, is there an above equivalent? as getting each individual background color programmatically and re-setting it isn't really feasible.

i've also tried setting the button itself to be invisible if selected as an attempt to hide the backgroundColor instead of change it like so:

```
if ([currentDay isSelected]) {
    [currentDay setAlpha:0];
} else {
    [currentDay setAlpha:1];
}
```

Which successfully hides the button on select but, you cant then click it again to show it as i guess the buttons gone and the image i have above it is also gone.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: u want to change the color of the button when it is selected and in normal states? am i right

Comment: @sreekanthk i have a default colour set in the storyboard, when its selected i want it to be clearColor, when its normal i want it to be back to the color it was before i changed it - without setting it explicitly to another color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (!sender.selected)
    {
        initialColor = sender.backgroundColor; // create an instance variable UIColor * initialColor;
        [sender setSelected:YES];
        [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
    else
    {
        [sender setSelected:NO];
        [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor initialColor]];
        [sender setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    }
}
```

if you have number of buttons,set tag to each button,and store the colour of each button background using UIColor * buttonColour,create a dictionary to store colour information,set each colour as an object with button tag as a key for it,in IBAction get the colour from dictionary using tag of sender(UIButton)....

Comment: again although this works, in the else statement you explicitly set another colour, i need it to revert back to it's default state (i have a million buttons all with different colours, so doing it this way isn't feasible)

Comment: this is what i hoped i didn't have to do, but thank you for confirming it haha :D

Answer (score 0):

put this checkmark in your button click event.it perfect work when ckick on button as first time then got to **Not Selected** and after click on second time go to **Selected**.

Default set Red color of button background.

```
-(IBAction)ClickBtn:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.selected  = ! sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected)
    {
        NSLog(@"Set Background Green color");
    }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"Set Background Red color");
    }
}
```

Comment: this only half works, as where you set red color, i need that to be what it was originally, not me setting it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.setBackgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:178.0/255.0 blue:2.0/255.0]
```

you can set your color according to your choice